# Infinitely scrolling display of web-scraped search results

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, pagination

My web application is simply supposed to take a search query, run a script on it that returns product information and then post it in an "endless" fashion on a web page, making one page with no pagination that is "infinitely" scrollable.

The web scraper I use, called Fletcher, which helps return usable results is slow to fetch each product matching the query. But, as soon as it returns information, I want to update my web page without refreshing it.

I'm thinking of the best way to do this so I don't have to refresh the page, but I don't know exactly where to start. I've had Ajax recommended and I find Backbone.js intriguing, but, really, I know I can do this with Erb, Ruby, Rails, and not too much else.

Please take a look at what I have. Any kind of code review at all will be helpful.

[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bfd1dad329d446a35da4)

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # before_filter :authorize
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end

  protected

  require 'open-uri'

  def authorize
    unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
      redirect_to login_url, notice: "Please log in"
    end
  end



  def nokoSearch (keywords, vendor)

    # def available (info)
    # if (info!=nil)
    # else
    # info = ""
    # end
    # end
    @product_links = Array.new

    @name = ""
    @description = ""
    @image = ""
    @price = ""

    keywords = keywords.split(' ').join('+')

    noko_links = Array.new
    base_url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/url=search-alias%3Daps"
    keyword_url = base_url + "&field-keywords=" + keywords

    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(keyword_url))
    @product_links = page.css("a").select{|link| link['class'] == "title"}
    @product_links.compact! # get rid of nils

    @product_links.each do |link|
      fletchedProduct = Fletcher.fetch link['href']

      @name = fletchedProduct.name
      @description = fletchedProduct.description
      if (fletchedProduct.image != nil)
        @image = fletchedProduct.image[:src]
      end
      @price = fletchedProduct.prices
      InfiniteProduct.create(:name => @name, :description => @description, :image => @image, :price => @price)
    end

  end

end
```

index.html.erb for the view:

```
<% @infinite_products.each do |infinite_product| %>
          <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <%= image_tag(infinite_product.image) %>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h5><%= sanitize(infinite_product.name) %></h5>
                                    <p><%= sanitize(infinite_product.description) %></p>
                                    <p><a class="btn primary details" href="#" rel="ajax/1.html"><i class="icon-zoom-in"></i></a> <a class="btn addto" href="#" rel="1">Add to <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a> <span class="label label-info price"><%= infinite_product.price %></span></p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class InfiniteProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /infinite_products
  # GET /infinite_products.json
  def index
    #nokoSearch("batman", "amazon")
    @infinite_products = InfiniteProduct.order(:name)


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @infinite_products }
    end
  end

  # GET /infinite_products/1
  # GET /infinite_products/1.json
  def show
    @infinite_product = InfiniteProduct.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @infinite_product }
    end
  end

  # GET /infinite_products/new
  # GET /infinite_products/new.json
  def new
    @infinite_product = InfiniteProduct.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @infinite_product }
    end
  end

  # GET /infinite_products/1/edit
  def edit
    @infinite_product = InfiniteProduct.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /infinite_products
  # POST /infinite_products.json
  def create
    @infinite_product = InfiniteProduct.new(params[:infinite_product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @infinite_product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @infinite_product, notice: 'Infinite product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @infinite_product, status: :created, location: @infinite_product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @infinite_product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /infinite_products/1
  # PUT /infinite_products/1.json
  def update
    @infinite_product = InfiniteProduct.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @infinite_product.update_attributes(params[:infinite_product])
        format.html { redirect_to @infinite_product, notice: 'Infinite product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @infinite_product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /infinite_products/1
  # DELETE /infinite_products/1.json
  def destroy
    @infinite_product = InfiniteProduct.find(params[:id])
    @infinite_product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to infinite_products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this without javascript because Rails is a server side language while you should work client side where the language to be used is Javascript.

Basically you should:

1-)Know when an user is near to the bottom of the page

2-)Send an ajax request to the url that returns informations (in json format so it will have to load a lot less data and will be easier to parse the result)

3-)Manipulate the DOM adding the new result returned by the ajax function.

Here there are some plugins in jQuery (a library written in javascript)
http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/#.T-NgN7R1Aak

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Matteo. Do you know how to use the form_tag and text_field_tag helpers in a .html.erb file to send an ajax GET request to a url and use the text_field's contents as params?

Comment: i don't think using rails method is the best way since they'll only create some javascript code, anyway i think that there's an attribute :remote to use ajax in forms while i advise you to use directly jquery

Comment: really it should be quite simple using one of the jquery code i've posted to you